# Nested table alignment?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I keep the rows aligned in the following nested tables?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
      <th>Column C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <input />
    <div><a href="#">Delete</a></div>
      </td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input  /></td>
        <td><input  /></td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" >Add</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. If you really have to, at least don't nest them.

Answer (score 1):

A really quick and simple way is to use two `br`s here

```
    <td><input /><br /><br /></td>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QZW8X/

You could also use `vertical-align`

```
    <td style="vertical-align:top;"><input /></td>
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QZW8X/1/

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off joining and/or splitting cells using **colspan** instead of nesting tables.  If your using Visual Studio, the Table menu allows you to do it visually.